# Error loading modules in nodejs, node and nom installed using repos Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I have installed nodejs and npm using repos in Ubuntu 12.10, and generally I install a module using

```
sudo npm install -g nodemodule
```

but when I try to do `var mod = require("nodemodule")` I receive an error I have to use `require("/usr/lib/node_modules/nodemodule")`, how canI fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the `NODE_PATH` environment variabele:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules/:$NODE_PATH
```

After that, try your Node script again. If it works, place the line above in your shells' startup file (usually `~/.bashrc`) so it will always be set when you log in.

Comment: Thanks, it did not work when added to `~/.bashrc` but it works with `~/.bash_profile`